# Visio Printing Page Size and Printer

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

My drawing page size and  Printer page size show they are the same in Visio printer page setup.
Print preview screen is blank and when I print there is nothing on the page

My goalis to have a A1 size readable print showing the complete flow chart.

I am using visio 2016 pro

Regards

Marcelle

Answer (score 0):

Check your layer properties ribbon **Home** -> **Layers** -> **Layer Properties**

Check all layers are set to print.

If that is ok then try selecting any one shape, open the shape's shapesheet and look in the **Miscellaneous** section cell **NonPrinting**.